# Error when trying to put ksp dependency in jetpack compose project

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

There are 2 dependencies already in the gradle. Room and ViewModel. I'm trying to use room but the project keeps crashing. I think its because of no ksp dependency.

So I included this line below in the build.gradle.kts(top level build file)

```
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false
```

Then I included this in the plugins in gradle (module)

```
id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
```

And also changed the kotlin extension version to 1.5.8

```
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.8"
```

Then i clicked on sync now and there were no errors.

But when i tried to include this line:

```
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")
```

Suddenly there are many errors.

So what am i doing wrong?

All dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    //ROOM
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")

    //VIEW MODEL
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0")

    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")
}
```

Comment: You need to make use of ksp version ```1.9.22-1.0.17``` with the kotlinCompilerVersion ```1.9.22```.

Comment: Also Don't forget to use java 19 for this project

Comment: @ChiragThummar Thanks. I changed the ksp version to 1.9.22-1.0.17. and changed this as well. ```id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @ChiragThummar, I made the following changes:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.22-1.0.17" apply false
}
```

The issue is now solved.

Comment: You can flag up my comments